# iOS library: how to use the delegate function

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, delegates

I have to use a library for my iOS project.
the library offers the class **ICDevice** (*abstract*) with a delegate **ICDeviceDelegate**.

the **ICDeviceDelegate** offers the following funtion

```
-(void)accessoryDidConnect:(ICISMPDevice *)sender;
```

I want to integrate this function in my **ViewController** to detect when the device is connected. How to do that?

Comment: Create an instance of ICDevice and set delegate to controller's self, or check if it has a sharedInstance then set delegate with it

Comment: refering to this class: https://github.com/mattlawer/iOS6-Private-Frameworks/blob/43ca814f3954ac8e409fcbb694cb660c2d50f346/ImageCapture/ICDevice.h  | its not abstract, how are you using this, show some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your `.h` and set your controller as delegate of the library `@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <LibraryDelegate>` so then you will be able to set your view controller as delegate when creating the library object

```
YourLibrary *library = [YourLibrary new];
library.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are a very important pattern in Cocoa/CocoaTouch, I suggest you read Apple's documentation to get a good grasp on it.

Once you understand them properly, it should be trivial to figure out the answer to your question.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11)